# plt.matshow: How to include a key describing color values in a correlation matrix

Tags: python-3.x

I am using plt.matshow to create a correlation matrix for a set of dataframe series as a step to preprocessing data for use in a data science project.  I would like to add a 'key' alongside the correlation matrix that describes the relationship between the colors and their numeric values.  Any ideas as to how to improve the readability of my current correlation matrix?

reviewed documentation for matplotlib.pyplot.matshow and matplotlib.pyplot without success in identifying attribute tools

```
 plt.matshow(xspace.corr())
 plt.xticks(range(len(xspace.columns)), xspace.columns, rotation = 
 'vertical')
 print(plt.show())
```

the resulting correlation matrix is as expected and does not include a key describing the relationship between the colors and the numeric correlation values between the series.

Answer (score 0):

In the lower right corner of the resulting correlation matrix, plt.show(), information relating to the numeric correlation value for the two series is given. Use the mouse pointer to observe any set on the matrix map.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this - the code is intended to name all the columns in the image and display a color bar with different levels describing the strength of the correlation:

```
# Compute the correlation matrix
corr_matrix = xspace.corr()

# Plot the correlation matrix
plt.matshow(corr_matrix)

# Add a color bar (legend) with vertical orientation
cbar = plt.colorbar(orientation='vertical')

# Set the tick labels on the color bar axis
tick_labels = [
    '-1.0 (Strong Negative): Strong negative correlation', 
    '-0.75: Moderate negative correlation', 
    '-0.5 (Moderate Negative): Moderate negative correlation', 
    '-0.25: Weak negative correlation', 
    '0.0 (No Correlation): No correlation', 
    '0.25: Weak positive correlation', 
    '0.5 (Moderate Positive): Moderate positive correlation', 
    '0.75: Moderate positive correlation', 
    '1.0 (Strong Positive): Strong positive correlation'
]
cbar.set_ticklabels(tick_labels)

# Annotate the color bar with a description
cbar.ax.set_ylabel('Correlation Level')

# Set the ticks on the axes to column names
plt.xticks(ticks=range(len(xspace.columns)), labels=xspace.columns, 
rotation='vertical')
plt.yticks(ticks=range(len(xspace.columns)), labels=xspace.columns)

plt.show()
```